# Magento 2.2.5 - Admin Panel has 503 Service Unavailable page under Content. Changes made to it are not reflected

Tags: magento-2.2.5

Magento 2.2.5 - Admin Panel has 503 Service Unavailable page under Content=>Pages. I updated this page but the changes are not reflected. Is Magento using this page or not?

[image]

Comment: Check your server logs, and Magento's logs (var/log), and add any relevant information from there to your question.

Comment: Also, when you say you "updated this page", what do you mean? What page did you update, and what changes did you make?

Comment: I did not see anything in Magento logs. Even before I edited the page, content in this page is not same as the 503 Page displayed when maintenance mode is enabled. Admin Panel 503 Page has the content "We're Offline...
...but only for just a bit. We're working to make the Magento Enterprise Demo a better place for you!"   But the page displayed has the content "Service Temporarily Unavailable
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later."

Comment: Looks like it is always fetching from pub/errors/default/503.phtml. Is there a setting to change to pick the page configured in Admin Panel.

Answer (score 0):

Magento's (admittedly lackluster) documentation suggests just intercepting the 503 at the server level and serving your own 503/maintenance page. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/comp-mgr/trouble/cman/maint-mode.html

I think common wisdom among Magento developers though, is to simply edit that file you already found: `pub/errors/default/503.phml`. When you enable maintenance mode, that is the file the Magento will load.

Comment: Thanks, I will try the steps in  https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/comp-mgr/trouble/cman/maint-mode.html. For customizing 404 page, I updated the Content=> Pages=> 404 not found page in the Admin and it worked fine. Similar way I wanted to update the existing 503 service unavailable page but it didn't work. Not sure why this page is listed in Admin if it is not configured to use.

Comment: Unfortunately, Magento does a lot of things that don't make sense